# Question about the implications behind “私でよければ“

Tags: meaning, expressions

Does is contain any romantic implications? I’ve heard it can be used as a love confession or marriage proposal of some sort, but is that true? And is that a common phrase?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All by itself without context, 「私{わたし}でよければ」 ***does not*** contain romantic implications.  How could it?  In fact, when I read your question, I murmured to myself 「私でよければ回答{かいとう}しましょうか・・」, roughly meaning "***If it's OK with you, I*** would post an answer."

「私でよければ」 simply means "If it is OK (with you), I ~~"

Even in a romantic context, 「私でよければ」 all by itself does not really mean much.  It is not a complete sentence in the first place.  You might use it in complete sentences such as:

> 「私でよければ付{つ}き合{あ}ってください。」　("If it is OK wih you, please date me.")
>
> 「（こんな）私でよければ結婚{けっこん}してください。」 ("If you find me acceptable, please marry me.")

「私でよければ」 is an ***extremely*** common phrase in all kinds of situations.  It makes you sound humble and not pushy/aggressive/impolite, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much. But I also should have posted the remaining half of the sentence “...いつでもご一緒しますよ” for better context.  Because on paper/literally, the sentence doesn’t really scream romantic implications to me. However, some people have told me that it reads unambiguously romantic, and I don’t know if I was truly subtext-blind to not have realized it. Hence why I ask here.

Comment: Uhmmm... p-please answer my second question? @l'électeur